# Kivy won't display image or label

Tags: python, kivy

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

class MyApp(App):
  def build(self):
    self.window = GridLayout(cols=1)
    self.window.add_widget(Image(source="logo.png"))
    self.greeting = Label(text="Hello", font_size=18)
    self.window.add_widget(self.greeting)

MyApp().run()
```

The terminal recognizes that an image and label have been imported but it won't display them in the window.

I'm expecting a window to pop up showing the image and label that I uploaded.

Comment: Your `build()` method should return `self.window`.

Answer (score 0):

The build() method needs to return the root widget, in this case self.window.

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.image import Image

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.window = GridLayout(cols=1)
        self.window.add_widget(Image(source="logo.png"))
        self.greeting = Label(text="Hello", font_size=18)
        self.window.add_widget(self.greeting)
        return self.window


MyApp().run()
```